# NodeJS, request-promises are not waiting for each other

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request

So I have broken my issue down a simple code snippet.

I want the `otherRequestes` to wait for my `firstRequests`, but somehow this is not working. the `firstRequested` is never waited for

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const firstRequest = () => {
  return rp('http://www.google.com')
    .then(function(htmlString) {
      console.log('in then of firstrequest');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('catch', err);
    });
}

laterRequest = (i) => {
  return rp('http://www.google.com')
    .then(function(htmlString) {
      console.log('in then' + i);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('catch', err);
    });

}

const requests = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  requests.push(laterRequest(i));
}

firstRequest().then(() => {
  Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
    console.log('all promises returned');
  });
});
```

So my desired output is "in then of firstrequest" after those there the output should be the laterRequests, I don't care for their order.

But when I run it currently my output is as follows the `firstRequest` ends up randomly somewhere in the output:

```
in then0
in then5
in then2
in then3
in then1
in then8
in then4
in then6
in then9
in then7
in then of firstrequest
all promises returned
```

Comment: The problem is, you start the 10 other requests in parallel with firstRequest - you need the for loop inside the firstRequest .then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the `for` loop you're calling all the other promises *before* you've called the first one. Call your first promise, then in the `.then()` (when you know its finished) start calling the other promises.

```
firstRequest().then(() => {
  const requests = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    requests.push(laterRequest(i));
  }

  return Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
    console.log('all promises returned');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `firstRequest` doesn't return a promise. You are already attaching a resolution handler to it by attaching a `.then` to it in the function.

You have a few different options for how to structure this code, but it looks like you want to have some things logged to the console when each promise succeeds or fails so you could do something like this:

```
const firstRequest = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // actually returns a promise now
        rp('http://www.google.com')
            .then(function(htmlString) {
                console.log('in then of firstrequest');
                resolve(htmlString); // promise resolves (i.e. calles its `.then` function)
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('catch', err);
                reject(err); // promise rejects (calles the `.catch`)
            });
    })
}

const laterRequest = (i) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rp('http://www.google.com')
            .then(function(htmlString) {
                console.log('in then' + i);
                resolve(htmlString);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('catch', err);
                reject(err);
            });
    })
}

const requests = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    requests.push(laterRequest(i));
}

firstRequest().then(() => {
    Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
        console.log('all promises returned');
    });
});
```

**Shorter answer**

You could also skip repeating `then`s and `catch`es and just return `rp`'s promise directly:

```
const firstRequest = () => rp('http://www.google.com');

const laterRequest = (i) => rp('http://www.google.com');


firstRequest().then(() => {

    const requests = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
        requests.push(laterRequest(i));
    }

    Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
        console.log('all promises returned');
    });
});
```

Comment: but this still doesn't change the order of the execution, I ran  both of your examples and I get the same result as above. firstrequest is getting executed last.

Comment: @acid just edited my short example. `firstRequest` is executing last because you're actually running the other functions before running `firstRequest`. I've changed this in my edit. Try it now.